# Adding node to Hyper-V Failover Cluster - Take disks online beforehand?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, failovercluster

We currently have a 2-node Hyper-V Failover Cluster. The nodes are connected to a SAN. Now we want to add a third node to the Cluster (which is also connected to the SAN).
When checking Disk Management on the new Node the disks are there but their state is offline (The disk is offline because of policy set by an Administrator).

The disks are Cluster Shared Volumes which are already actively used on the existing 2 nodes.

My question is: Should I take the disks online manually (rightclick -> online) before joining the node to the Cluster or will this happen automatically when joining the node?

Answer (score 0):

Only one cluster node owns the Cluster Shared Volumes at a time. The disks will show offline in the disk management MMC on all non-owner nodes. No, you should not bring the disks online before joining the new node to the cluster. Access to the Cluster Shared Volumes is managed by the cluster.

Comment: That is not a 100% true. When Disk1 is owned by Node1, Node2 sees them as "Reserved", but Online. Now when I join Node3 with all Disks offline, then move ownership of Disk1 to Node3, will it be automatically taken online or will all VMs stored on Disk1 lose their Disk and go into critical-state?

Comment: If these disks are members of your Cluster Shared Volume then just join the new node to the cluster. You don't need to do anything with the disks. The cluster will manage the disks. If you move the CSVFS volume owner to another node the VM's won't lose access to their disks. That's the point of Cluster Shared Volumes in a Hyper-V Failover Cluster.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just want to be cautious, hence the question.